# The functions .all() or .any() from LinQ crashes when using it on an array of long

Tags: c#, api, linq

I'm currently creating an API for my database which contains Users and Sites. They have a many-to-many relation. When I did my "Get" function, I wanted it to be the most generic possible : It can have a random number of parameters and even an "order by" parameter.
One of the parameters is ofcourse the sites of the users which is a long[] of Ids.
I want that ALL of my ids in my array corresponds in the id of the Sites in my User.

Ex : List[1,3] => If my User have Sites 1,2,3 is ok but if he has 1,2,4 it's not ok.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUser(IEnumerable <long> idSites){
...
resultUsers = DBContext.Users.Where(x => (idSites.Count() > 0)
                                                    ? (x.Sites.Count() > 0)
                                                        ? idSites.All(id => x.Sites.All(site => site.Id == id))
                                                        : false
                                                    : true).ToList();
...
}
```

For a sake of clarity I only put this parameter in the where() but normally all my parameters are in the where().
The first ternary expression is to check if if I want to filter on this parameter.
The second one is to avoid an empty list of sites counting as "ok" when it's not (i don't know why it was working but whatever).

The first .all() never gave me any problems.
The second one crashes in my opinion whether I put all() or any().

I'm going to put the error BUT I know it won't help. The error says I can't assign my line to my list because it misses the "ToList()" function. It's because it is crashing mid lambda expression and never gets to the "toList()" (in my opinion).

EDIT : When I put "AsEnumerable" the error is removed, but my returned list is always empty (when i put don't filter on that parameter it's full).
And more than that, I can't use the .include() functions when I use this tag, which I use to get the value of the Sites.

There it is :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
    .Where(u => DbSet<Dictionary<string, object>>("SiteUser")
        .Where(s => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
            objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u, "Id"), 
            objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s, "UsersId")))
        .Join(
            inner: DbSet<Site>(), 
            outerKeySelector: s => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s, "SitesId"), 
            innerKeySelector: s0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s0, "Id"), 
            resultSelector: (s, s0) => new TransparentIdentifier<Dictionary<string, object>, Site>(
                Outer = s, 
                Inner = s0
            ))
        .Count() > 0 ? __complexUserParameters_idSites_0
        .All(id => DbSet<Dictionary<string, object>>("SiteUser")
            .Where(s1 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u, "Id"), 
                objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s1, "UsersId")))
            .Join(
                inner: DbSet<Site>(), 
                outerKeySelector: s1 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s1, "SitesId"), 
                innerKeySelector: s2 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(s2, "Id"), 
                resultSelector: (s1, s2) => new TransparentIdentifier<Dictionary<string, object>, Site>(
                    Outer = s1, 
                    Inner = s2
                ))
            .All(ti0 => ti0.Inner.Id == id) == True) : False)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

If you need any more information to help me let me know.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: The error tells you that the query cannot be translated to sql, so you are using methods which are not supported. A workaround(that might be expensive) would be to use `AsEnumerable` before you use the problematic methods. Then the latter part of the query is executed in memory instead of in the database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hey, thanks for your response.
When I do what you're suggesting, the error is indeed removed.
But the result is now always an empty list whenever this parameter is involved.
And more than that, I am using the .Include() method after my .Where() which, after putting AsEnumerable(), is innaccessible.

Comment: I think you should change the second All method on Any: idSites.All(id => x.Sites.Any(site => site.Id == id)).

Comment: @4lexKislitsyn Hey, thank you also for your answer.
I also though about that too, I just tried it again with your suggestion and the result is the same.
Without AsEnumerable it crashes and with with it, it always result an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Count instead of All. It should work:

```cs
var query = context.Users.AsQueryable();
if (sites?.Count > 0)
{
  query = query.Where(user => user.Sites.Count(site => sites.Contains(site.Id)) == sites.Count);
}

return await query.ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
```

`HttpContext.RequestAborted` can be used as `cancellationToken`. Of course you could add `.Include(x => x.Sites)`.

If `sites` variable is array `Count` must be changed on `Length`.

Comment: hey again !
What you proposed work just fine !
Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could Check [Intersect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0) (should be fine on int-s)?

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUser(IEnumerable <long> idSites){
 if (idSites == null || !idSites.Any())
 {
   resultUsers = DBContext.Users.Tolist(); //Why checking the Count of the input parameter on every User? 
 }
 else
 {
   resultUsers = DBContext.Users.Where(x => x.Sites.Count() > 0 ?
                                         idSites.Intersect( x.Sites).Count() == idSites.Count() :                                        
                                          false)
                                .ToList();
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your answer !
I tried in both sides, with x.Sites.Intercect and with idSites.Intercect and in both cases it says it doesn't exist in this format (even though it was proposed by autocompletion).